# Looking for a free video stream or Mjpeg stream to stream on local network

Tags: video, video-streaming, mjpeg

Do you know of a software that can stream desktop or window as video stream or mjpeg?

I have tried vlc but keeps crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) - it's pretty versatile.